# How to get image from HTTP URL in Windows Phone?

Tags: http, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

How do I get image from http url, my url is like:

```
"http://accd.com/abc.htm",
```

how do I get image from it?

Comment: Your image is in the html?

Comment: yes, my image type will be Base64

Comment: If your image is a url, just put image like <image source="yourUrl" />. It's works.

Comment: He he so I deleted the comment as soon as I added.

Comment: @MatDev8 my image is not url, but it comes from http url, so how to call that url and as a response my image will be Base64, so how to call it?

Answer (score 1):

So

```
public static BitmapImage Base64StringToBitmap(string source)
    {
        var ims = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(source);
        var dataWriter = new DataWriter(ims);
        dataWriter.WriteBytes(bytes);
        dataWriter.StoreAsync();
        ims.Seek(0);
        var img = new BitmapImage();
        img.SetSource(ims);
        return img;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the web client like this :

```
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://accd.com/abc.htm"));
    webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, eventArgs) => (eventArgs.Result); //Here is your base 64 image code, you can use the Base64StringToBitmap function
```

Answer (score 1):

May be with using a webclient

```
 WebClient wc = new WebClient();  
 wc.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(wc_OpenReadCompleted);  
 wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("your http url"), wc);  

 void wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapImage.SetSource(e.Result);
                imgLogoData.Source = bitmapImage;
                imgLogoData.Height = 200;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(AppResources.resErrorOccured);
                ExceptionHelper.WriteLog(ex);
            }
        }
```

And to convert a Base64 string to BitmapImage just follow this method

```
public static BitmapImage base64image(string base64string)
    {
        byte[] fileBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64string);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length))
        {
            ms.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.SetSource(ms);
            return bitmapImage;
        }
    }
```

So that, for an Image declared in xaml like this

Add an image to your XAML, such as this:

```
<Image x:Name="imgLogoData" Height="50" Width="50" />
```

You can then set the source, like this:

```
imgLogoData.Source = base64image(yourBase64string);
```

Comment: thanks very much brother but what should I write in XAML page to bind image

Comment: and my image type response is Base64, so how to convert it in above method?

Comment: imgLogoData is the Image Control that you shall declare in xaml